# Move or delete file out of folder if detox reports "cannot rename"

Tags: rename, delete

I'm backing up recipes in a folder to a backup drive. I use `cp -vnpr /folder/* bkdrive/folder` so not overwriting or copying same files over and over. Works well. Then I started getting copy problems because of "odd" characters and such.

I started using `detox -r -v` to clean up file names and that also worked well. Almost. When I go to recover directory, I have older files from before I started using `detox` plus the cleaned up files. If I run `detox` against this directory I get `cannot rename bkdrive/file this or that.pdf to bkdrive/file_this_or_that.pdf` because file already exists. Yep I agree.

Is there a way to get  `detox` to `rm` or `mv` to `/other_folder` a file in this case? I guess another option would be to `> detox_results.txt` and `rm` or `mv` files from directory to another based on the line that begins "Cannot rename"...I just don't have a clue as to how. I have hundreds of megs of files in there.

Newer to Linux user.

Comment: I'd switch from `cp` to `rsync`. It does the job you wanna do all in one, without further renaming the stuff.

Comment: Thanks but not what the question is. Detox removes junk from filenames and exceptionally well too. Using the noclobber option with cp works extremely well also only backing up newer files. I don't think rsync cleans junk characters from files nor does tar backups. Issue is before I started using Detox and backing up folder. I now have for instance file!%*name.txt which would Detox to file_name.txt but unable to do that because file_name.txt is already in directory and it shows that by creating a line that starts with 'Cannot rename.....' followed by whatever the name is.

Comment: I think I'm getting closer. I've tried this;

#!/bin/bash

detox -r -v * > /path/to/folder/out.txt 2>&1

# Get the file names and subfolder names from the input file
cat /path/to/folder/out.txt | grep "Cannot rename" | awk -F'[(./)]' '{print $2, $4}' | while read file folder; do
  # Make the junk folder and move the file
  mkdir -p junk/$folder
  mv $folder/$file.txt junk/$folder
done

It only moves file from root folder but not any of the subfolders.